# Derivative and extrema problem

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f(x) = x^{2} \sin(1/x) + x^{3}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, asuume that $f(0) = 0$.

1. Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Does $f$ have a local extremum (minimum or maximum) at $x = 0$? Explain.

For part 1, I tried to use definition of derivative, but don't know how to compute derivative of $f(x)$ correctly.

For part 2, because $f'(0)=0$, I think $f$ has a local extremum. But I don't know if my thought is correct.

Answer (score 0):

(a) For $x=0$,
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = 
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2\sin(1/x) + x^3 }{x} =
\lim_{x\to 0}(x\sin(1/x) + x^2) = 0.
$$
For $x\ne 0$, f is differentiable because is a sum of a product of a composition... of differentiable functions.
(b) The implication is local extremum $\implies$ derivative = 0. The point $x=0$ can't be a local extremum because $f$ takes values $>0$ and $<0$ near $x=0$ (why?).

Comment: could you explain more about differentiability for x not equal to 0?

Comment: @ash, the function $x\mapsto 1/x$ is differentiable in any point $\ne 0$ because is a quotient of differentiable functions (constant 1 and the identity). The function $x\mapsto\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable in any point $\ne 0$ because is a composition of differentiable functions ($\sin$ and the previous function)...